# How to do full outer join with two fields from PostgreSQL db?

Tags: sql, postgresql, outer-join

I'm trying to do a full outer join with two fields from a PostgreSQL db? Below are both of the SQL queries I would like to combine to using an full outer join. I would greatly appreciate your help!

```
SELECT ci.NAME_VALUE NAME_VALUE FROM certificate_identity ci WHERE ci.NAME_TYPE = 'dNSName' AND reverse(lower(ci.NAME_VALUE)) LIKE reverse(lower('%{}'));".format(domain_name))

SELECT ci.NAME_VALUE NAME_VALUE FROM certificate_identity ci WHERE ci.NAME_TYPE = 'emailAddress' AND reverse(lower(ci.NAME_VALUE)) LIKE reverse(lower('%{}'));".format(domain_name))
```

Comment: You are not clear. Do you mean you want the full outer join of those two queries? If so, the full outer join on what condition? Do you undertand that full outer join on returns inner join on rows plus unmatched left & right table rows extended by nulls? [mcve] please.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered `OR`?

```
SELECT ci.NAME_VALUE as NAME_VALUE
FROM certificate_identity ci
WHERE (ci.NAME_TYPE = 'dNSName' AND 
       reverse(lower(ci.NAME_VALUE)) LIKE reverse(lower('%{}'))
      ) OR
      (ci.NAME_TYPE = 'emailAddress' AND 
       reverse(lower(ci.NAME_VALUE)) LIKE reverse(lower('%{}'))
      );
```

I see nothing in the question that suggests `FULL JOIN`.

Comment: @Gordon_inoff Thanks for your reply! What do you mean, I see that the entire questions suggests outer join? Can you please specify?

Comment: @bedford . . . Solving this problem with `full join` is not the right approach.